# Atualizar Dinamicamente a Sessão php com jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom, tenho a função abaixo que, com JQuery, atualizo os label's de exibição dos valores do carrinho.

Tudo funciona:

```
  function add(_quant, _preco, _total, _estoque) {
      quantidade = parseInt($("#"+_quant).val());
      estoque = parseInt($("#"+_estoque).val());
      preco = parseFloat($("#"+_preco).val());

      novaQuantidade = quantidade + 1;

      if(novaQuantidade <= estoque) {         
          if(novaQuantidade == 0) {
              alert("Quatidade não por ser 0");
          } else {
              total = novaQuantidade * preco;                 
              $("#"+_quant).val(novaQuantidade) ;
              $("#"+_total).html(total.toFixed(2));
              $(".totalCarrinho").html(total.toFixed(2));
              $(body).load('_required/sessaoCarrinho.php?idProduto=' + _quant + '&novaQuantidade=' + novaQuantidade);
          }
      }  else {
              alert("Quatidade escolhida maior que estoque");
      }
  }
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo atualizar também na session do php.

Estou tentando assim:

```
$(body).load('_required/sessaoCarrinho.php?idProduto=' + _quant + '&novaQuantidade=' + novaQuantidade);
```

E, no php assim:

```
  $idProduto = $_GET["idProduto"];
  $novaQuantidade = $_GET["novaQuantidade"];

  foreach ($_SESSION["carrinho"] as $key=>$produtoC) {
       if($produtoC[$idProduto] == $novoProduto->getIdProdutos()) {
           $achou = true;
           $chave = $key;
           $estoque = $novoProduto->getEstoque();
           break;                
       }
   }

   if($achou == true) {
       if ($estoque > $_SESSION["carrinho"][$chave]["quantidade"]) {
          $_SESSION["carrinho"][$chave]["quantidade"] = $novaQuantidade;
       }       
   }
```

Mas a session não esta sendo atualizada.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Para atualizar uma sessão, recomendo matar a sessão anterior... para que ela limpe e e recrie a sessão. use `unset($_SESSION['carrinho']);`, não esqueça de colocar no header: `session_start();`

Comment: No código php que você citou não está presente a função `session_start()`, mas como o código aparentemente não está completo vale dar uma conferida nas linhas acima se esta função foi chamada. Sem ela as alterações na sessão não serão persistidas.

Comment: o comando "$(body).load(...);" indica que você quer substituir todo o conteúdo de body pelo retorno do load. Use o comando "$.get(...);" para fazer a requisição sem carregar o retorno no body...

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim

JavaScript:

```
function add(_quant, _preco, _total, _estoque) {
    quantidade = parseInt($("#"+_quant).val());
    estoque = parseInt($("#"+_estoque).val());
    preco = parseFloat($("#"+_preco).val());

    novaQuantidade = quantidade + 1;

    if(novaQuantidade <= estoque) {         
        if(novaQuantidade == 0) {
            alert("Quatidade não por ser 0");
            }
            else {
                total = novaQuantidade * preco;                 
                $("#"+_quant).val(novaQuantidade) ;
                $("#"+_total).html(total.toFixed(2));
                $(".totalCarrinho").html(total.toFixed(2));
                //
                $("#div_vazia_qualquer").load('_required/sessaoCarrinho.php',{
                    idProduto:_quant, 
                    novaQuantidade:novaQuantidade}, function(resposta){
                        alert(resposta);
                    });
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Quatidade escolhida maior que estoque");
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$idProduto = $_POST["idProduto"];
$novaQuantidade = $_POST["novaQuantidade"];

foreach ($_SESSION["carrinho"] as $key=>$produtoC) {
   if($produtoC[$idProduto] == $novoProduto->getIdProdutos()) {
        $achou = true;
        $chave = $key;
        $estoque = $novoProduto->getEstoque();
        break;                
   }
}

if($achou == true) {
   if ($estoque > $_SESSION["carrinho"][$chave]["quantidade"]) {
      $_SESSION["carrinho"][$chave]["quantidade"] = $novaQuantidade;
   }       
}
```

Comment: não deu. Como eu testo se está encontrando o arquivo php?

Comment: No php ponha um `echo` qualquer e execute, o script vai dar um alerta com o que ele receber do `echo`

Comment: não esta dando. Acho que é diretório. Tenho o arquivo php na pasta _required. E o arquivo que chama o .js esta na pasta que esta pasta _required esta junta. Tipo>  index.php, _required/, topo.php. Esta certo?

Comment: Está certo, mas e o .js está em qual pasta?

Comment: <script src="../_global/_js/carrinho.js"></script> e o php, direto _required

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como adivinhar. Veja o que a requisição do load() está retornando. No seu navegador web vá em inspecionar elemento, vai ter uma aba chamada rede (network) nela filtre as requisições ajax e veja o que foi enviado para o servidor e o que foi retornado como reposta. Isso varia de navegador para navegador. Ai  você pode identificar se está acontecendo algum erro de sintaxe no php;

Comment: fiz assim, deu certo,    
     $("body").load('_required/sessaoCarrinho.php',{
                    idProduto: idCampo, 
                    novaQuantidade: novaQuantidade,
     });, mas esta indo para a página php e parando lá.